# why main thread don't return response immediately when I call async method?

Tags: asp.net, async-await

I have write a test code in a new web application as below:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Logger.Write("start Index,threadId:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        MyMethodAsync(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);//no await and has warning
        Logger.Write("end Index,threadId:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return View();
    }

private async Task MyMethodAsync(HttpRequest request)
    {
        Logger.Write("start MyMethodAsync,threadId:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await SomeMethodAsync(request);
        Logger.Write("end MyMethodAsync,threadId:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
```

And here is the log:

2017-11-15 19:55:31.904 start Index,threadId:35

2017-11-15 19:55:31.919 start MyMethodAsync,threadId:35

2017-11-15 19:55:31.919 end Index,threadId:35

2017-11-15 19:55:53.324 end MyMethodAsync,threadId:46

The client brower will receive response at about 2017-11-15 19:55:32 and it accord with my understanding. In my actual project production environment,it writes the same log as above, However, the client brower received response in about 22 seconds later at about 2017-11-15 19:55:54. It seems that even the main thread complete the work, the main thread do not return the response until the new thread complete the work.

I have debug this problem serveral days. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

`async-await` does not change the HTTP protocol. The request goes to the server, the server produces a response and sends it to the client.

It just changes how ASP.NET requests are processed by ASP.NET.

And it doesn't make the request handling faster. Quite the contrary.

But it does use more thread pool threads and makes the server more responsive under heavy load.

Comment: Thank you Paulo Morgado. I know what you said. But why the same code in differenct solution has differenct response time?